# Can't run same tcl code through tcl script?

Tags: linux, tcl

I can run the same code by going to `tclsh`from my Konsole but when i try to run it using a tcl script, it gives no output.

I have a file named `name` which contains this

`my name is dev
 my name is vaibhav`

When i run the command through `tclsh` , it gives the required output.

Command is `exec grep "dev" name` and Output is `my name is dev`

But when i run it through tcl script named `call.tcl`, it gives no output! Its contents are :-

```
#! /usr/bin/tclsh
exec grep "dev" name
```

I have verified the address of tclsh in the first line and the file is present there. I am using `redhat-release-5Client-5.5.0.2`


Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use interactive `tclsh`, the result from the `exec` command will be returned and by default they will be printed in the console.

But, when you run at as a standalone script, it won't be printed to console (stdout) unless you manually use the `puts` command to print the same.

```
puts [exec grep "dev" name]
```

Also, you can save it to a variable using `set` command

```
set result [exec grep "dev" name]
puts $result
```

Comment: Also, it's usually a mistake to use grep from Tcl; Tcl's both good at searching files itself, and inclined to treat a failure by grep to find anything as an exception.